# Center multiple UIViews in a row its superview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How would I go about placing arrays of identical sized uiviews at their superviews center?

For example: I have an array of (x number) of 50x50 sized views.. that I place right next to each other in a line. How can I center that line of 50x50 views, to the center of their superview?

Is there an easier way than what I'm thinking I'd have to do?

My approach would to take the count of views inside the array, and multiply it by 50. This would give me the width of the images together.

Then subtract that width from the width of the superview. Then place the subviews based off that math.

Is there an easier approach to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are suggesting is one way of doing it. Another way that has the advantage of keeping the views centered when you rotate the device is to do this:

1. Create a basic UIView to use as a container
2. Set the container `bounds` property to (0, 0, 50 * x, 50)
3. Layout the 50x50 subviews inside the container so they fill it
4. Add the container view as a subview of the main view
5. Set the `center` property of the container to the center of the superview
6. Set the `autoresizingMask` property of the container view to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`

Comment: If I did this, could I add the 50x50 views to the containers superview in the same location , then remove the container?

Comment: No, but why would you want to? The container is an invisible view that keeps the 50x50 views centered in the main view. I get the impression that you think that view layout should be easier and simpler than it is. It is not - it can be tricky and hard to get right especially when device rotation is taken into account. Stop worrying, bite the bullet, implement it and move on to more interesting aspects of your app's logic.

Comment: The reason I can't leave it in the container is because of the way I need to have users manipulate those views once they're set on the screen. Being confined in a container will not work for what I'm doing with them.

Comment: So lay them out like you originally suggested. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Yeah, after I posted my response. I was like.. duh! Thanks man!

Comment: Instead of actually adding the views to the container view.. I just took the CGPoint containerView.frame.origin, and used that as a starting point in placing my views on the view controllers view. Works perfectly. :)

Comment: That's a very round-about way of doing the math that you originally proposed without the extra benefits of automatic layout when you rotate the device. However, if it works for you then go with it.

Comment: With my application, it only needs to support one orientation, otherwise, I'll have to go about it another way. The way I manipulate the views, works best if it's on the view controllers view.

Answer (score 1):

Use the center property of the UIView

Apple documentation says that: The center property can be used to adjust the position of the view without changing its size.

So you would do something like this:

Create a UIView that will contain all the 50x50 Views with a width of [array count] x 50;
Then add all the 50x50 views to this Container View.
Add this view to the desired view and then set its center point to its superview center point.

Something like this:

```
[my50x50ContainerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [50x050ViewsArray count] x 50, 50.0)];
[self.view addSubview:my50x50ContainerView];
my50x50ContainerView.center = self.view.center;
```